# Create custom sales rule in magento 2 based on previous orders quantity

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to create a sale rule in Magento 2 that allow using a coupon code several time  until a total amount of orders is reached.
example : while total client orders are under 1000 euro he can use a custom coupon code for a reduction of 30%.
What is the best way to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Short answer - with a standard Magento coupon - you can't. You'll need a plugin - if you ask for a recommendation, it'll be off-topic for SO I'm afraid; you might be better off asking on https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible out of the box. You'll probably need an additional module for that.

Here are a few options that may help achieving that:

- [Extended Shopping Cart Rules](https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extended-shopping-cart-rules.html) (mirasvit)
- [Advance Promotions for Magento 2](https://www.magedelight.com/advance-promotions-extension-magento-2.html) (MageDelight)
- [Special Promotions](https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html) (Amasty)

All of these modules adds the option to create promotions and limit its use based on the amount spent on the store. So you can create your coupons accordingly.

You can also check a [list of Magento module vendors](https://www.magenteiro.com/blog/modulos-magento/) on this link. Most of them have Promotion modules.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The first module met my requirements , Thanks.